# Enable Remote Desktop in Windows Firewall from command line

Tags: windows, command-line, remote-desktop, windows-firewall, unattended

*note: #command-line tag do not imply batch-file-only, I will accept a PowerShell script or any freely available utility, which can be started from command line and finish its work unattended.*

---

### tl;dr

how to unattendedly transform firewall rules exactly to state GUI puts it, on Windows Vista to Windows 10 of any interface (display) language?

### Elaborating

This question is similar to [#786383](https://superuser.com/questions/786383/how-to-enable-remote-assistance-and-add-an-exception-for-it-in-windows-firewall), but it's not the same.

Basically, because answer isn't good for me:

1. `set rule group="remote desktop" new enable=Yes` opens port 3389 for public networks, and I want to avoid that. Also, different Windows languages have different group names, but I need an universal solution.
2. `netsh firewall set service type = remotedesktop mode = enable` isn't working for me either: it is deprecated since win7, and allows rdp for current network only (if you're in public one, 3389 will be opened for public networks and won't work in private networks afterwards).

Note that before RDP is enabled via GUI, there is only one rule per protocol for RDP. But when RDP is enabled via GUI, port only gets opened for private and domain networks, and rules split for this. After enabling, there are 4 rules in Windows 8+ and 2 rules (no UDP) in Windows XP, Vista and 7.

Work-around I'm currently using is adding my own rules:

```
netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="Remote Desktop - User Mode (TCP-In)" dir=in action=allow program="%%SystemRoot%%\system32\svchost.exe" service="TermService" description="Inbound rule for the Remote Desktop service to allow RDP traffic. [TCP 3389] added by LogicDaemon's script" enable=yes profile=private,domain localport=3389 protocol=tcp
netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="Remote Desktop - User Mode (UDP-In)" dir=in action=allow program="%%SystemRoot%%\system32\svchost.exe" service="TermService" description="Inbound rule for the Remote Desktop service to allow RDP traffic. [UDP 3389] added by LogicDaemon's script" enable=yes profile=private,domain localport=3389 protocol=udp
```

but that's bad, because (unlike standard ones) they can be modified by user, have no group (to work with other scripts), and don't get automatically disabled when RDP is turned off via GUI.

### Screenshots

Firewall rules before enabling RDP via GUI for the first time [*](https://superuser.com/questions/904353/enable-remote-desktop-in-windows-firewall-from-command-line#) [**](https://superuser.com/questions/904353/enable-remote-desktop-in-windows-firewall-from-command-line#)
[image]

Same rules when RDP is enabled via GUI (state I want to get):
[image]

And after disabling RDP in GUI:
[image]

---

I won't retell the whole story of this fight with windows command line utilities, until somebody asks. Here is [that story in Russian](http://blog.it.mobilmir.ru/post/117011888551/windows).

Comment: So am I correct in to summarize that you want the 2 built in firewall rules that enable UDP/TCP on Port 3389 for only the Domain and Private profiles?

Comment: almost. First, yes, I'm about modifying built-in rules. Second, yes, I want built-in rules to enable 3389 on Domain and Private networks. But here goes the tricky part (otherwise it would already be answered): let's first say about TCP. By default, there are no separate rules for {Public} and {Doman, Private} networks. There is one rule for {All} networks. But when RDP is enabled via GUI, there appears two rules, one for {Public} and one for {Doman, Private}. Same with UDP. Also I added screenshots, may clarify a bit also.

Answer (score 11):

```
netsh firewall set service type = remotedesktop mode = enable
```

or

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Comment: I tried that. `netsh firewall` is deprecated (since win7), does not work in Win10, and allows rdp for current network only (if you're in public one, rdp will be allowed for public networks and won't work in private networks afterwards). This is noted in original story, I just thought it's not worth mentioning in question. I'll fix that fault.

Comment: While indeed deprecated, `netsh firewall` still works in Windows 10 (tested on Pro).

Comment: @Twisty I confirm, it works in version 1607 (build 14393.693) indeed. When I've been writing my prev comment, I tested it in current version (there were no release yet), and it didn't work.

Comment: I can confirm this works for Windows 8.1. This is the only answer that truly helped me. I don't know why I couldn't find "Remote desktop" in the GUI firewall settings.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the question correctly this will get you what you want. This is PowerShell:

```
$FireWall = New-Object -comObject HNetCfg.FwPolicy2
$EnableRules = $FireWall.rules | Where-Object {$_.LocalPorts -like "*3389*" -and $_.Profiles -eq "3"}
ForEach ($Rule In $EnableRules){($Rule.Enabled = "True")}
```

This will filter out the rules and grab the correct rule names agnostic of language. It does this by filtering on port 3389 and finding the rule associated with "Domain and Private networks". `Profiles -eq 3` is the bitmap mask for Private and Domain networks, you can see the reference here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366303(v=vs.85).aspx

Where 1 (Domain networks) + 2 (Private networks) = 3

Here is the MSDN link where I figured out the rest:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365309(v=vs.85).aspx

And here is how I figured out what the properties and methods were for the other objects:

```
PS C:\> $FireWall | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{98325047-c671-4174-8d81-defcd3f03186}

Name                                         MemberType            Definition
----                                         ----------            ----------
EnableRuleGroup                              Method                void EnableRuleGroup (int, string, bool)
IsRuleGroupEnabled                           Method                bool IsRuleGroupEnabled (int, string)
RestoreLocalFirewallDefaults                 Method                void RestoreLocalFirewallDefaults ()
BlockAllInboundTraffic                       ParameterizedProperty bool BlockAllInboundTraffic (NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2...
DefaultInboundAction                         ParameterizedProperty NET_FW_ACTION_ DefaultInboundAction (NET_FW_PROFI...
DefaultOutboundAction                        ParameterizedProperty NET_FW_ACTION_ DefaultOutboundAction (NET_FW_PROF...
ExcludedInterfaces                           ParameterizedProperty Variant ExcludedInterfaces (NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_...
FirewallEnabled                              ParameterizedProperty bool FirewallEnabled (NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_) {get...
IsRuleGroupCurrentlyEnabled                  ParameterizedProperty bool IsRuleGroupCurrentlyEnabled (string) {get}
NotificationsDisabled                        ParameterizedProperty bool NotificationsDisabled (NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_...
UnicastResponsesToMulticastBroadcastDisabled ParameterizedProperty bool UnicastResponsesToMulticastBroadcastDisabled...
CurrentProfileTypes                          Property              int CurrentProfileTypes () {get}
LocalPolicyModifyState                       Property              NET_FW_MODIFY_STATE_ LocalPolicyModifyState () {g...
Rules                                        Property              INetFwRules Rules () {get}
ServiceRestriction                           Property              INetFwServiceRestriction ServiceRestriction () {g...



PS C:\> $Rules | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{9c27c8da-189b-4dde-89f7-8b39a316782c}

Name                 MemberType Definition
----                 ---------- ----------
Action               Property   NET_FW_ACTION_ Action () {get} {set}
ApplicationName      Property   string ApplicationName () {get} {set}
Description          Property   string Description () {get} {set}
Direction            Property   NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION_ Direction () {get} {set}
EdgeTraversal        Property   bool EdgeTraversal () {get} {set}
EdgeTraversalOptions Property   int EdgeTraversalOptions () {get} {set}
Enabled              Property   bool Enabled () {get} {set}
Grouping             Property   string Grouping () {get} {set}
IcmpTypesAndCodes    Property   string IcmpTypesAndCodes () {get} {set}
Interfaces           Property   Variant Interfaces () {get} {set}
InterfaceTypes       Property   string InterfaceTypes () {get} {set}
LocalAddresses       Property   string LocalAddresses () {get} {set}
LocalPorts           Property   string LocalPorts () {get} {set}
Name                 Property   string Name () {get} {set}
Profiles             Property   int Profiles () {get} {set}
Protocol             Property   int Protocol () {get} {set}
RemoteAddresses      Property   string RemoteAddresses () {get} {set}
RemotePorts          Property   string RemotePorts () {get} {set}
serviceName          Property   string serviceName () {get} {set}
```

Comment: not sure why, but it says there's no such a property http://i.imgur.com/A0OmzZ8.png. I guess this is because until RDP is enabled 1st time via GUI, there is no such a rule, there is *single rule for all networks* (public, private, domain). But when enabled via GUI, this rule is split! Also there's typo at `)}`

Comment: on Windows 8, there is no error, but nothing is done altogether http://i.imgur.com/te0J1Q9.png. Firewall rules look before enabling RDP via GUI for the first time: http://i.imgur.com/sEIE0me.png, after enabling and then disabling via GUI: http://i.imgur.com/PjnFOh1.png. Same rules when RDP is enabled via GUI (state I want to get): http://i.imgur.com/c3ywfHy.png

Answer (score 2):

The following cmd commands..

```
netsh firewall set service type = remotedesktop mode = enable
```

and

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /
```

are not sufficient to enable remote desktop.

I had to add this one to make it work (Client: Windows 10).

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Remote Desktop" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=3389 action=allow
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for PowerShell solution, the following can be used:

```
Enable-NetFirewallRule -Name "RemoteDesktop-UserMode-In-TCP"
Enable-NetFirewallRule -Name "RemoteDesktop-UserMode-In-UDP"
```

Comment: This name is only valid for a specific Windows version, and only English UI.

Comment: @LogicDaemon: are you sure about restricted to English UI? Since at least Windows 7, there are two fields for the name of the rule, and it creates confusion; in the context of `*-NetFirewallRule`, `DisplayName` is the field with the localized name, while `Name` has a less verbose content, English-based but invariable, using a stricter, no-whitespace syntax. Also for `group`, while `"remote desktop"` is accepted, the actual content is `@FirewallAPI.dll,-28752`, which is also invariable.

Comment: @AntoineL I don't remember now, but I think I've tested that at the time of writing my comment.